# Problem with game on react. How can I make it so that the timer is set only under certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

**This I think is the focal point**

```
// Funzione per gestire il click su una carta (lettera)
  const handleCardClick = (letter) => {
    if (flippedCards.includes(letter) || !isGameStarted) {
      return
    }

    // Aggiorna l'array delle lettere girate
    const updatedFlippedCards = [...flippedCards, letter]
    setFlippedCards(updatedFlippedCards)

    // Controlla se tutte le lettere sono state girate
    if (updatedFlippedCards.length === alphabet.length - 1) {
      // Se rimane solo un giocatore, termina il gioco assegnando il punto
      const remainingPlayers = players.filter(
        (player) => !eliminatedPlayers.includes(player)
      )
      if (remainingPlayers.length === 1) {
        setIsGameStarted(false)
        handleRoundEnd()
        return
      }

      // Altrimenti, termina il gioco e determina il vincitore del round
      setIsGameStarted(false)
      handleRoundEnd()
    } else {
      // Passa al giocatore successivo non eliminato
      let nextPlayerIndex = (currentPlayerIndex + 1) % players.length
      while (eliminatedPlayers.includes(players[nextPlayerIndex])) {
        nextPlayerIndex = (nextPlayerIndex + 1) % players.length
      }

      setCurrentPlayerIndex(nextPlayerIndex)

      // Se ci sono almeno due giocatori rimanenti, avvia il timer
      const remainingPlayersCount = players.filter(
        (player) => !eliminatedPlayers.includes(player)
      ).length
      if (remainingPlayersCount > 1) {
        setTimer(10)
      }
    }
  }
```

**And this is the complete code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'

// Array contenente le lettere dell'alfabeto
const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')

// Componente per la visualizzazione della lista dei giocatori
const PlayerList = ({ players, onDeletePlayer }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Giocatori:</h2>
    <ul>
      {players.map((player, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          {player}
          {/* Bottone per eliminare il giocatore */}
          <button onClick={() => onDeletePlayer(index)}>Elimina</button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)

// Componente per la visualizzazione della tabella dei punteggi
const ScoreTable = ({ players, scores, eliminatedPlayers }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Punteggi:</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Giocatore</th>
          <th>Punteggio</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {players.map((player, index) => (
          <tr
            key={index}
            // Aggiunge la classe 'eliminated' se il giocatore è stato eliminato
            className={eliminatedPlayers.includes(player) ? 'eliminated' : ''}
          >
            <td>{player}</td>
            <td>{scores[index]}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
)

// Componente principale dell'applicazione
const App = () => {
  const [flippedCards, setFlippedCards] = useState([]) // Array delle lettere girate
  const [isGameStarted, setIsGameStarted] = useState(false) // Flag per indicare se il gioco è in corso
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10) // Timer per il conteggio del tempo
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]) // Array dei giocatori
  const [inputName, setInputName] = useState('') // Nome del giocatore da aggiungere
  const [roundWinner, setRoundWinner] = useState(null) // Vincitore del round
  const [scores, setScores] = useState([]) // Punteggi dei giocatori
  const [currentPlayerIndex, setCurrentPlayerIndex] = useState(0) // Indice del giocatore corrente
  const [eliminatedPlayers, setEliminatedPlayers] = useState([]) // Giocatori eliminati
  const [currentRound, setCurrentRound] = useState(1) // Numero del round corrente
  const [showNextRoundButton, setShowNextRoundButton] = useState(false) // Prossimo round
  const [showStartNextRoundButton, setShowStartNextRoundButton] =
    useState(false)
  const [finalWinner, setFinalWinner] = useState(null) // Ultimo giocatore rimasto
  const [shouldEndRound, setShouldEndRound] = useState(false) // Determinare se è il caso che il round finisca
  const [remainingPlayersCount, setRemainingPlayersCount] = useState(0)
  const [lastPlayerRemaining, setLastPlayerRemaining] = useState(false)

  // Array per tenere traccia dei giocatori eliminati in ciascun round
  const [eliminatedPlayersByRound, setEliminatedPlayersByRound] = useState([])

  // Effetto per gestire gli eventi della tastiera
  useEffect(() => {
    let countdown

    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      const pressedKey = event.key.toUpperCase()
      const currentLetterIndex = alphabet.indexOf(pressedKey)

      // Controlla se il gioco è in corso e la lettera premuta è valida
      if (isGameStarted && currentLetterIndex !== -1) {
        handleCardClick(pressedKey)
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)

    // Avvia il timer se il gioco è in corso
    if (isGameStarted) {
      countdown = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1)
      }, 1000)
    }

    // Pulisce gli eventi quando il componente viene smontato
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
      clearInterval(countdown)
    }
  }, [isGameStarted, currentPlayerIndex, currentRound])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer === 0 && isGameStarted) {
      // Se il timer è scaduto, elimina il giocatore corrente
      setEliminatedPlayers([...eliminatedPlayers, players[currentPlayerIndex]])
      resetTimer()
      handleRoundEnd() // Chiamata a handleRoundEnd dopo aver eliminato il giocatore
    }
  }, [timer, isGameStarted, currentPlayerIndex, players, eliminatedPlayers])

  // Funzione per gestire il click sul pulsante "Inizia"
  const handleStartClick = () => {
    // Imposta il numero iniziale di giocatori rimasti
    setRemainingPlayersCount(players.length)
    setIsGameStarted(true)
    setTimer(10)
  }

  // Funzione per gestire il click su una carta (lettera)
  const handleCardClick = (letter) => {
    if (flippedCards.includes(letter) || !isGameStarted) {
      return
    }

    // Aggiorna l'array delle lettere girate
    const updatedFlippedCards = [...flippedCards, letter]
    setFlippedCards(updatedFlippedCards)

    // Controlla se tutte le lettere sono state girate
    if (updatedFlippedCards.length === alphabet.length - 1) {
      // Se rimane solo un giocatore, termina il gioco assegnando il punto
      const remainingPlayers = players.filter(
        (player) => !eliminatedPlayers.includes(player)
      )
      if (remainingPlayers.length === 1) {
        setIsGameStarted(false)
        handleRoundEnd()
        return
      }

      // Altrimenti, termina il gioco e determina il vincitore del round
      setIsGameStarted(false)
      handleRoundEnd()
    } else {
      // Passa al giocatore successivo non eliminato
      let nextPlayerIndex = (currentPlayerIndex + 1) % players.length
      while (eliminatedPlayers.includes(players[nextPlayerIndex])) {
        nextPlayerIndex = (nextPlayerIndex + 1) % players.length
      }

      setCurrentPlayerIndex(nextPlayerIndex)

      // Se ci sono almeno due giocatori rimanenti, avvia il timer
      const remainingPlayersCount = players.filter(
        (player) => !eliminatedPlayers.includes(player)
      ).length
      if (remainingPlayersCount > 1) {
        setTimer(10)
      }
    }
  }

  // Funzione per gestire il cambio del nome del giocatore da aggiungere
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setInputName(event.target.value)
  }

  // Funzione per aggiungere un giocatore alla lista
  const handleAddPlayer = () => {
    if (inputName.trim() !== '') {
      setPlayers([...players, inputName.trim()])
      setScores([...scores, 0])
      setInputName('')
    }
  }

  // Funzione per eliminare un giocatore dalla lista
  const handleDeletePlayer = (index) => {
    const updatedPlayers = [...players]
    const updatedScores = [...scores]
    updatedPlayers.splice(index, 1)
    updatedScores.splice(index, 1)
    setPlayers(updatedPlayers)
    setScores(updatedScores)
  }

  // Funzione per gestire il click del pulsante "Invio" durante l'inserimento del nome del giocatore
  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      handleAddPlayer()
    }
  }

  // Funzione per gestire la fine del round
  const handleRoundEnd = () => {
    resetTimer()

    const remainingLetters = alphabet.filter(
      (letter) => !flippedCards.includes(letter)
    )

    const remainingPlayers = players.filter(
      (player) => !eliminatedPlayers.includes(player)
    )

    if (remainingPlayers.length === 1) {
      // Se rimane solo un giocatore, assegna la vittoria senza avviare il timer e il turno
      setScores((prevScores) => {
        const newScores = [...prevScores]
        const winnerIndex = players.indexOf(remainingPlayers[0])
        newScores[winnerIndex]++
        return newScores
      })

      setCurrentRound((prevRound) => prevRound + 1)
      setEliminatedPlayersByRound((prevEliminatedPlayers) => [
        ...prevEliminatedPlayers,
        eliminatedPlayers,
      ])
      setEliminatedPlayers([])
      setCurrentPlayerIndex(0)
      setIsGameStarted(false)
      setRoundWinner(remainingPlayers[0])
      setShowNextRoundButton(true)
    } else {
      // Altrimenti, gestisci il round come prima
      let nextPlayerIndex = (currentPlayerIndex + 1) % players.length
      while (eliminatedPlayers.includes(players[nextPlayerIndex])) {
        nextPlayerIndex = (nextPlayerIndex + 1) % players.length
      }

      setCurrentPlayerIndex(nextPlayerIndex)
      setIsGameStarted(true)
      setRoundWinner(null)
      setShowNextRoundButton(false)
    }
  }

  // Funzione per gestire il reset del gioco
  const handleResetClick = () => {
    setFlippedCards([])
    setIsGameStarted(false)
    setTimer(10)
    setPlayers([])
    setInputName('')
    setRoundWinner(null)
    setScores([])
    setCurrentPlayerIndex(0)
    setEliminatedPlayers([])
    setCurrentRound(1)
    // Resetta l'array degli eliminati per ogni round
    setEliminatedPlayersByRound([])
  }

  // Funzione per gestire il click del pulsante "Comincia Nuovo Round"
  const handleStartNextRoundClick = () => {
    setFlippedCards([])
    setIsGameStarted(false)
    setTimer(10)
    setCurrentPlayerIndex(0)
    setShowStartNextRoundButton(false)
    setRoundWinner(null)
  }

  // Funzione per resettare il timer
  const resetTimer = () => {
    if (isGameStarted) {
      setTimer(10)
    }
  }

  // Funzione per renderizzare le carte (lettere)
  const renderCards = () => {
    return alphabet.map((letter, index) => (
      <div
        key={index}
        className={`card ${flippedCards.includes(letter) ? 'flipped' : ''}`}
        onClick={() => handleCardClick(letter)}
      >
        {flippedCards.includes(letter) || !isGameStarted ? '' : letter}
      </div>
    ))
  }

  // Restituisce la struttura dell'applicazione
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <h1>Gioco delle carte</h1>
      {/* Visualizza la lista dei giocatori */}
      <PlayerList players={players} onDeletePlayer={handleDeletePlayer} />
      {/* Visualizza la tabella dei punteggi */}
      <ScoreTable
        players={players}
        scores={scores}
        eliminatedPlayers={eliminatedPlayers}
      />
      {isGameStarted ? (
        <>
          <p>Turno di: {players[currentPlayerIndex]}</p>
          <p>Tempo rimanente: {timer} secondi</p>
        </>
      ) : roundWinner ? (
        <>
          <p>Vincitore del round: {roundWinner}</p>
          <button
            onClick={handleStartNextRoundClick}
            disabled={!showNextRoundButton}
          >
            Comincia Nuovo Round
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Inserisci il nome del giocatore'
              value={inputName}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
            />
            <button onClick={handleAddPlayer}>Aggiungi Giocatore</button>
          </div>
          <button onClick={handleStartClick}>
            Inizia il {currentRound}° round
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={handleStartNextRoundClick}
            disabled={!showStartNextRoundButton}
          >
            Comincia Nuovo Round
          </button>
        </>
      )}
      <div className='cards-container'>{renderCards()}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**With its basic css:**

```
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  text-align: center;
}

.cards-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.card.flipped {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: transparent;
}
```

**And the main.jsx:
**

```
import React from 'react'

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

import App from './App.jsx'

// Usa createRoot().render al posto di ReactDOM.render
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

*I would like the moment there is only one player remaining in the round the timer doesn't start and the player gets the win directly, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. *